# Missing Authorization header for a privileged call on connection - Logic App API for SQL

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I deployed Logic Apps and its SQL API from ARM.

Triggering Logic Apps produce error "Missing Authorization header for a privileged call on connection" for SQL create a new row Trigger.

What I need to do?